# Web Interface to interact with Label Matrix

Tags: matrix, label, zpl

I am in the process of creating a system that can print labels. The designs have been created in Label Matrix, but I need the ZPL (Zebra Programming Language). Does anyone know if I can go from Label Matrix to ZPL?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new ZebraDesigner ZPL driver to the system and use a file as the port. Then when you "Print" the document, it will write the ZPL code to the file.

Note that it might have some header information before the first `^XA` which you might not need.

Also, how to add a local port for a driver:

1. Go to `Printer Properties`
2. Click on the `Ports` tab
3. Click `Add Port`
4. Select `Local Port` and click `New port`
5. Enter a filename e.g. `C:\output.zpl`
6. Make sure it is checked in the ports list
7. Now all printing output should go to `C:\output.zpl`

Alternatively, can just click Print, tick "Print to file" checkbox, output to a *.prn file, open that file with Notepad and the code is there.

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful! I was able to print directly from Label Matrix to a .txt file. Under the print menu, there is a small box that says "print to file" and that did exactly what I needed. It was helpful to add the printer (detailed above) as well. Thanks again for the timely and useful support.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to print it to a txt file! Please consider upvoting my answer also. It helps! Peace!